# How use microphone sound level to start arecord and or aplay

Tags: pi-3b+, bash, microphone, speakers, arecord

I start a simple project which use 2 raspberry. Both have microphon and speaker, and a button.
The button starts the aplay and arecord commands for both of raspberry. And the full duplex communication starts.. The following command start on both raspberry, with different ip adress of course.

```
arecord --duration=100 --format=S16_LE --rate=16000 | ssh pi@10.0.2.x aplay --durantion=100 --format=S16_LE --rate=16000
```

The principle of communication is ok, but I observe a limitation created by Larsen effect. Other point, I have no possibility to give more space between speaker and micro (about 50mm), and that's why I have larsen effect.

So Do you know if it is possible to filter the sound level in order to reduce the Larsen effect ? Or other good idea that could help in this project ?

Some orientation seems to be interesting :

```
arecord --vumeter=mono
```

Which show the % level of the microphone, so a solution could be to disable the unused micro when the used micro has a % level up to 50% ... but how integrate it into the code ?

Other orientation : what is the use of chanel in alsa mixer ? Is a possibility to configure chanels in order to optimise use of arecord and aplay ?

Thanks a lot.